# Why is it called an axolotl tank?

Tags: dune

Early in the book *Dune Messiah*, the readers are introduced axolotl tanks, which are tanks that can reproduce livings beings (at least according to the Wiki). Why are they referred to as this. Axolotls are these weird amphibians from the Latin American area, I believe, so I don't know why they would be used as a name for a tank that reproduces life. Why is it so?

Comment: My time has come to burn! I invoke the ancient power that I may return!

Comment: Axolotls are just freakin' cool???

Comment: Is it just a coincidence that ‘axolotl’ has the same consonants as ‘Tleilaxu’ (though in a different order)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Dune Encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dune_Encyclopedia) notes that the term itself is (as is so often the case with Tleilaxu technology) shrouded in mystery. This is such a common feature of their naming process as to engender the idea that their names are *deliberately misleading* and hence that close inspection therefore will reveal nothing.

> Tleilaxu terms have always drawn close inspection because of a mocking habit of giving, almost of *flaunting*, hints about their processes and purposes. Why, for example, 'axolotl' tanks? Axolotl is the term for the tadpole form of the genus Ambystoma, a species of Terran amphibian now found only on Ecaz. Thus, Dr. A would argue that the tank was so named because of the animal's ability to mature sexually without undergoing metamorphosis if its habitat was dry, but to become a salamander in pools of water, hence, the waters of the tank give us a different "animal." No, would say Dr. B, the Tleilaxu use the term because these amphibians are able to regenerate lost bodily parts, and perhaps the secret of that ability is part of the process. On the contrary, would say R.M.C of the Bene Gesserit: ancestral voices tell us that the term comes from an extinct Terran language, Nahuatl, in which atl means "water" and xolotl means "spirit," and therefore it is simply a fancy epithet for the tank's chemical ability to give life from "the spirit-of the water."

Comment: When a later novel reveals what axolotl tanks actually are, the Tleilaxu secrecy regarding their methods makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 19):

Probably because axolotls can regenerate limbs.  It's an easy jump from there to using the same process (whatever it is!) to regenerate entire bodies.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axolotl) for more.

Answer (score 1):

The name of Axolotl comes from the Aztec myth of the (now differently transliterated) Xolotl, the sinister twin of Quetzalcoatl.

Shamelessly pasting Wiki:

> Xolotl accompanied Quetzalcoatl to Mictlan, the land of the dead, or
>   the underworld, to retrieve the bones from those who inhabited the
>   previous world (Nahui Atl) to create new life for the present world,
>   Nahui Ollin, the sun of movement. In a sense, this re-creation of life
>   is reenacted every night when Xolotl guides the sun through the
>   underworld.